# Why quotient space is needed?

Tags: soft-question, vector-spaces

I was wondering why quotient space is so important? Let say for vector space why quotient space is needed? Please explain!

Comment: Let $V$ be the $\mathbb Q$-vector space of rational Cauchy seuqnces, let $U$ be the subspace of zero sequences. Then the quotient space $V/U$ has some nice properties (turns out it is a complete Archimedian ordered field) and is widely used throughout mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

It is important for vector spaces because of the theorem that for every surjective linear map $f : V \to W$ the map $f$ induces an isomorphism between the quotient space $V / \text{Kernel}(f)$ and $W$. There are similar theorems in other categories.